# What are the common causes of Thread Failure in Java

Tags: java

We have a Java 8 Application that has the Printer Thread failing / not responding intermittently I was just wondering what the most common causes of a thread Failure would be, my understanding is that a Thread can't be garbage collected so that can be rules out, locking of the thread is possible we are using a LinkedList add remove and isEmpty. A Stack Out of Memory for the thread that is possible only if it would't effect the Main thread or other threads. And OutOfMemory Heap isn't likely because it would effect the entire program. The thread that is failing / hanging is basically a Worker Thread adds to the LinkedList by calling the printSystem threads method to add to the linkedlist and then notifies the same threads run method that is waiting to read from the linked list.

```
 // This method is called by a Worker Thread to add a print message.
 printAdd(object message) {
    synchronized(this)
    { 
      printList.add(message);
      try {
      this.notifty();
      }
      catch(Exception e){} 
   } 
 }

 run() {

 while(true)
   synchronized(this)
     try{
     this.wait();
      while(!printList.isEmpty()) {
             message = printList.remove();
             // Code not show but determines the message type
             // And then sends to the correct printer  


      }
     }
     catch(Exception e){}
   }            

   }
}
```

Comment: Try reading the exception messages.

Comment: Your thread is most likely hanging out on `IO`. To investigate the problem run `strace -f <java_pid>` and examine the output. Try to find some `write`/`sendmsg`/etc... sycalls. That **might** shed the light on the problem.

Comment: `catch{}` is not legal Java. The common causes of thread failure are the same as the common causes for any failure. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If the thread throws something that goes uncaught, that will end up killing the thread. It is really brittle to rely on having a single dedicated thread just because of this kind of thing. maybe try having an uncaught-exception-handler on the thread to log what's killing it? Btw be aware this isn't a good way to use wait (without a condition variable).

Answer (score 0):

As user207421 Mentions Threads failures are the same as the common causes for any failure and in addition because Threads are dealing with shared variables that are locked Threads can also hang due to Thread Deadlocks. I think in the above example the printList.isEmpty() not being Synchronized is possibly the problem. One solution might be to move from a LinkedList that isn't ThreadSafe to a Thread Safe Alternative like the BlockingQueue Interface.